# How can I reconstruct the Google admin console URL for each user?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to be able to reconstruct the following URL, but when I use the API/SDK I cannot find where/how google stores the user identifier (in bold font below). Does anyone know where this comes from?

https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#UserDetails:user=**147n2zr2klf814**

Thanks for your time :)

- Jason

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that user value is internal to Google.  I have never been able to find any API call that returns that value.

Maybe an okay compromise would be constructing the search URL instead?

```
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#UnifiedSearchResults:query=<primaryEmail>&tab=USERS
```

It won't take you directly to the user page, but the only result should be the user.